# Will Hibernate saveOrUpdate method delete children?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an application that loads objects via hibernate and then passes those objects to another tier as detached objects. Any changes to those objects are sent back down to the hibernate tier where I call `saveOrUpdate()` on those objects.

Will hibernate delete one-to-many relationship child objects contained in a collection in the objects that are passed into `saveOrUpdate()` if I simply remove the child object from the collection before calling `saveOrUpdate()`?

If not, then how would this typically be accomplished in a hibernate application that uses detached objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will hibernate delete one-to-many relationship child objects contained in a collection in the objects that are passed into `saveOrUpdate()` if I simply remove the child object from the collection before calling `saveOrUpdate()`?

No, not by default.  Such child objects are known as "orphans" in this context, assuming that some other entity doesn't also have a reference to them.

This is discussed in the docs, [11.11. Transitive persistence](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive):

> A special cascade style, `delete-orphan`, applies only to one-to-many associations, and indicates that the `delete()` operation should be applied to any child object that is removed from the association. Using annotations there is no `CascadeType.DELETE-ORPHAN` equivalent. Instead you can use the attribute orphanRemoval as seen in Example 11.4, “`@OneToMany` with `orphanRemoval`”. **If an entity is removed from a `@OneToMany` collection or an associated entity is dereferenced from a `@OneToOne` association, this associated entity can be marked for deletion if `orphanRemoval` is set to true**.

Comment: That makes sense. However, when I set CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true on the collection the child object is still not deleted. Could this be due to the fact that I am using a JoinColumn annotation in conjunction with the OneToMany annotation?

Comment: @Tom: Probably not, no, `@JoinColumn` is just used to override the default join column name. It seems that Hibernate doesn't think that it's an orphan.  Are you sure some other entity doesn't have a reference to that child?

Comment: It is definitely not referenced from another entity. The underlying db relationship is actually a ManyToMany, however, and I am using the OneToMany with JoinColumn to make the model simpler. Maybe that is throwing it? Otherwise I also just noticed that some child entities of the child contain ManyToOne relationships which cannot have the orphanRemoval attribute set on them. Maybe that is preventing deletion of the parent somehow.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it will not. You could use @Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHANS) to achieve that.